# lost sound ubuntu 14.04, tried everything

Tags: 14.04

Today my sound stopped working, I have tried several things listed in the forums and still rolled a big fat 0.
Here is my Alsa Info.

```
!!Script ran on: Tue Jul 8 05:51:51 UTC 2014


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
Product Name: Satellite L55-A
Product Version: PSKLAU-01200E
Firmware Version: 1.20


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release: 3.13.0-30-generic
Operating System: GNU/Linux
Architecture: x86_64
Processor: x86_64
SMP Enabled: Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version: k3.13.0-30-generic
Library version: 1.0.25
Utilities version: 1.0.27.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

0 [PCH ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
HDA Intel PCH at 0xc8610000 irq 44


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)



!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[ 11.321684] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[ 11.321884] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 11.343623] SKU: Nid=0x1d sku_cfg=0x40f79a2d
--
[ 11.344245] realtek: Enabling init ASM_ID=0x9a2d CODEC_ID=10ec0269
[ 11.353890] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[ 11.355657] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[ 11.355708] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[ 11.633485] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

Comment: Did you try alsamixer (from a terminal) to see if sound is not simply muted ?

Comment: yeah, i also reinstalled everything listed in other post. no matter what i try i can't get sound

Comment: May be a silly suggestion: If you're using external speakers, have you accidentally unpluged them / turned the off?

Comment: If you dual boot with Windows 8, [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/464444/258567). If headphones work, and the speaker doesn't work or works intermittently, please click "Does this bug affect you?" in the upper left of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the common soundcard drivers packages:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: No external speakers, and i just installed the soundcard packages and still nothing

Comment: I'm stumped with this one

Comment: Try with --purge and reinstall. i edited the answer.

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: still nothing..

Comment: And all of a sudden the sound is now working.
Not sure what happened, I tried everything suggested, turned off the computer and did a cold boot each time with a fail each time, then all of a sudden the sound just started working

Comment: it has to reboot after installation. I couldnt mention it.

Comment: @user301484 See this answer of mine: http://askubuntu.com/a/466627/258567